# Enable chrome extension when a tab is opened matching a url

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

I am pretty new to Chrome extensions and Javascript so any help will be great. Currently I have an extension that takes the currently playing song on tunein.com and populates links to search for the song on Spotify, YouTube, Google Play Music and Google. [GitHub link here for reference](https://github.com/WoozyFetus/TuneInToSpotify/tree/master/CurrentlyPlaying). I'm currently enabling the extension when you are actively on the tab where tunein.com is playing but I would like to be able to make it work even when that tab is in the background.

I also worry if this will break my current implementation where I am traversing the DOM to get the name of the song and artwork. A lot of the tutorials I was using to develop this have mainly focused on the activeTab. From my cursory research I would set a flag in localStorage and do a check when a new tab is opened but I'm not sure how to access the DOM of a tab in the background or if that is even possible.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: In the `popup.js`, just remove the constrains from `chrome.tabs.query(...)` call, loop through `tabs` and decide to which tabs to send messages based on their URL.

Comment: `how to access the DOM of a tab` - an instance of content script that is declared in manifest.json runs inside each matching web page regardless of its focused state.